# Run the same SAS program in parallel with different argument

Tags: sas

I am currently working on optimizing a script in SAS EG.
The script basically has to be run for each month since 2012 **on a daily-basis**.
Up until 2022 the code for all periods took less than 24 hours to run but every now and then, it exceed this treshold.

The process (which is a macro) is structured as follow:

- Retrieve data from several Oracle tables
- Transform (transpose/concatenate...)
- Compute statistics based on explicit rules
- Delete statistics for the given month in `Result` Oracle table
- Insert the new statistics for the given month in `Result` Oracle table

The reason why it takes so much time is because we run the program sequentially, looping on every periods.

```
%macro run_all_periods;
    %let start_date = 31jan2012; *  define start date;
    %let i = %sysfunc(inputn(&start_date, date9.)); *   date format;

    *   define last date to be considered   ;
    %let today = %sysfunc(inputn(%sysfunc(date(), date9.), date9.)); *  today;
    %let last_date = %sysfunc(intnx(month, &today,-1, e)); * last period to be considered;

    %do %until (&i > &last_date); * do loop for all reference periods until last_date;
        %let date=%sysfunc(putn(&i, date9.));   
        %run_script(period=&date);   
        %let i = %sysfunc(intnx(month, &i, +1, e));  * following period;
%mend;
```

As the periods are independant to each other (i.e., it doesn't matter the order for which it run) I think that it would be better to run all periods in parallel instead of optimizing the script in itself.

Therefore, is there any way to run the same script in SAS EG in parallel with different argument (in my case periods)?

---

At the same time, we are currently testing SAS Viya at work. While looking into the functionnalities, I found out about the [Background Submit](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/webeditorcdc/v_006/webeditorug/p08kgz0784ii4qn146oujkc1m4rw.htm).

> You can run a saved SAS program, query, task, or flow as a background submission, which means that the file can run while you continue to use SAS Studio. You can view the status of files that have been submitted in the background, and you can cancel files that are currently running in the background.

And the associated note caught my eye:

> Note: Because a background submission uses a separate compute server, any libraries or tables that are created by the submission do not appear in the Libraries section of the navigation pane in SAS Studio

Would it be possible to leverage this functionnality to run several times the same script in background with different periods ?

Comment: This post seems to suggest you can: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Studio/Can-you-programmatically-do-background-job-submit-in-SAS-studio/td-p/643744

Comment: Tested it, it does work.

Comment: Do you have SAS/Connect licensed for your base SAS 9.4 installation?  That can let you trigger new SAS sessions from your current session that can run in the background.

Comment: rsubmit or calling the SAS executable with the program passed in directly will work. rsubmit is your best choice though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least ten different ways to do this, both on SAS 9.4 and SAS Viya.  Viya is a bit more "native" to this concept, as it tries to do everything as parallel as possible, but 9.4 would also do this no problem.

- Command line submission - you can write a .bat/.ps1/shell script/etc. to run SAS for each of your jobs, and submit them all in parallel.  That's how we do it usually - we call SAS once for each job.
- SAS/CONNECT - using [MP CONNECT](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi29/124-29.pdf), this is very easy to do. Just make sure you have it set up to run things in parallel and not wait until the point you want it to wait for (if any exists).
- Grid multiprocessing - using the [SAS Grid Manager](https://support.sas.com/en/software/grid-manager-support.html).  Not that different from how SAS/CONNECT works, really.  You use [PROC SCAPROC](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p12q6hgd4v0ka7n11axliohfcbfh.htm) to analyze the program and identify splits, or just do it yourself.
- Background submits in SAS Studio - this is possible in both 9.4 and Viya.  Each job is in a separate session.  This is somewhat manual though, so you'd have to submit each job by hand.
- Use Python to do the parallelization, then SASPy (94) or SWAT (Viya) to submit the SAS jobs.
- Directly call SAS (using x command) for each of your sub-jobs
- Use EG's built in ability to run multiple processes at once - see [The SAS Dummy](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2009/02/11/multitasking-in-eg/) for more.
- Use EG's [scheduling interface](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/Run-multiple-Process-Flows-at-once-using-SAS-Code-on-EG-7-11-HF3/td-p/292962) to run multiple jobs
- Use the [built-in SAS Scheduler](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2013/08/14/four-ways-to-schedule-sas-tasks/) to run the various jobs
- Modify your script to use BY group processing so that you can do the whole thing at once but still take advantage of efficiencies (some jobs this will work for, some it won't).